# Dragon character with non dragon group?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, balance, dragons, party

I'm looking for dragon as a player character that doesn't destroy the game -- if it is too powerful for the players who don't play dragons it is not a desirable choice.

I would like to play a character as a dragon.  Most of what I found was related to 3.5e and dragons from *Draconomicon*.

A template that I found for a 5e [dragon-as-PC as that this link](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?438478-Dragon-Player-Characters), but judging from the comments at that site it has balance problems.  (Too strong at the beginning, poor later).

1. How can I make this template work?
2. What modifications will make it a better fit to the 1 to 20 class level progression that other classes/archetypes have?

Comment: If this question gets re-opened, I would suggest that the only viable answers are those from *anyone who has play tested that particular dragon-as-PC-prototype.*  From the link provided, it was NOT playtested before it was posted, and thus whatever balance issues it has have not been substantiated so far.  That means that any answer from someone who has not tried this out will tend to be opinion based, and run afoul of the Good Subjective/Bad Subjective criteria.

Comment: I have edited the question to try and make it a better fit for the site.  I don't think downloading the entire pdf into the question is viable, but we do worry about "link based questions" and having links break. (See WoTC forums being canned and links to posts there breaking).

Comment: Does anyone have any solution to this question?

Comment: If nobody else has play tested that proposed dragon/character, it is hard to come up with an answer that fits this site's format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any homebrew-based would, like KorvinStarmast aptly said, be very opinionated unless carefully and extensively playtested. I'd like to offer another tool however: reflavouring.

Dragonborn, and Aarakockra, (available from the [elemental evil's player's companion](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/EE_PlayersCompanion.pdf)) could easily be reflavoured as a half-dragons or a dragons cursed in semi-humanoid form (which is a great adventure hook by itself).

That said, if you're willing to go all the way, and the rest of the party wants to play along, you could create a draconic campaign. Start the players off as wyrmling dragons of a type of their choice (maybe they were in a bunch of eggs from a smuggler who accidentally kept them too warm which allowed them to hatch?), and balance encounters accordingly. It can make for a very interesting campaign, though very far off the beaten path.

Comment: So, these solutions seem to me to be good, but then there is another problem. How to make me as a player does not become a subject in the hands of other players. I mean Wyrmling dragon sounds good, but then:
- How to determine such Wyrmling a possible fight (a fight in DD are common) -
- What about the mental development? Young, the annual dragon, will be able to resolve obstacles that will give MG? I mean, come up with solutions.

Comment: Mentally, most dragons are on par with humans already at wyrmling level. As for the rest, that is the DM's job. It should be relatively easy to create normal challenges for a dragon party, though not recommended for a beginning DM.


Edit: apparently enter posts instead of inserting a newline.